# Join strings contained in lists

Tags: python

I would like to create a list of joined strings, where the joined strings were once lists within another list. I suppose I could use a for-loop, but was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this. See below for an example and expected output.

Starting list:

```
x = [
      ['2019','4'],
      ['2019','3'],
      ['2019','2'],
      ['2019','1']
    ]
```

Expected output:

```
[
 '20194',
 '20193',
 '20192',
 '20191'
]
```

Comment: `list(map(''.join, x))`

Comment: Wow! You're amazing @yatu! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @yatu mentioned in a comment, the solution I was looking for (avoiding for-loops) is this:

```
list(map(''.join, x))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [
      ['2019','4'],
      ['2019','3'],
      ['2019','2'],
      ['2019','1']
    ]
y = [i[0]+i[1] for i in x]
print(y)
```

By this you can iterate over all the array elements and concatenate the elements of sub-array using **+**.

Output -

```
[
 '20194',
 '20193',
 '20192',
 '20191'
]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will remember from this point onward. 

Comment: You can still [edit this answer](/posts/62410648/edit) to add an explanation.